# Protocol buffer data to python dictionary , gRPC message to Dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, protocol-buffers, grpc, grpc-python

I have data from gRPC.
Which is type of protocol buffer,
It looks like to dictionary, but it is not.
For my case:
The type of data: <class 'google._upb._message.RepeatedCompositeContainer'>
data:

```
 [manufacturer_device_id: "B0000B0204c45bbefa948b"
  scale: Days
  bucket_epoch_seconds: 1698552000
  bucket_epoch_seconds: 1698638400
  channel_usages {
   channel: 1
   usages: 798.64540227509769
   usages: 1353.0604314283914
  }
]
```

Now, i want to convert the above data to python dictionary.
How can i do this, can anyone help me?
Advance thanks

I have tried to convert protocol buffer response (message)  to python dictionary.

Comment: Currently, i use regular expression to extract my necessary info.
But if some other system you guys can provide, i will be grateful .

Comment: Maybe the `from google.protobuf.json_format import MessageToDict` class could help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [MessageToDict](https://googleapis.dev/python/protobuf/latest/google/protobuf/json_format.html),

```
from google.protobuf.json_format import (
    MessageToDict,
)

request_data_dict: Dict = MessageToDict(
    message,
    preserving_proto_field_name=True,
    use_integers_for_enums=False,
    including_default_value_fields=True,
)
```

**Where**,

`message` – The protocol buffers message instance to serialize.

`including_default_value_fields` – If True, singular primitive fields, repeated fields, and map fields will always be serialized. If False, only serialize non-empty fields. Singular message fields and oneof fields are not affected by this option.

`preserving_proto_field_name` – If True, use the original proto field names as defined in the .proto file. If False, convert the field names to lowerCamelCase.

`use_integers_for_enums` – If true, print integers instead of enum names.